# Ads are not being shown up via Facebook Ads Library Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some of pages has active ads in facebook ads library but it doesn't appear when accessing it the ads library api

In ads library i can see the active ads: [https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=US&view_all_page_id=2000786836855475&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=page&media_type=all](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=US&view_all_page_id=2000786836855475&sort_data%5Bdirection%5D=desc&sort_data%5Bmode%5D=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=page&media_type=all)

but using api it returns empty string

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/ads_archive?media_type=all&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ad_reached_countries=US&ad_active_status=ACTIVE&limit=500&search_page_ids=2000786836855475